# Creating a new matrix from an existing one while only storing the first two columns in python

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have an existing matrix:

```
    matrix = [[3,5,7,9],
              [6,8,12,14],
              [2,1,0,5],
              [7,8,9,10]]
```

I am trying to extract just the first two columns from any matrix and store them in another matrix.

For example, I'm hoping the new matrix would look like:

```
   new_matrix = [[3,5],
                 [6,8],
                 [2,1],
                 [7,8]]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `new_matrix = [[i[0],i[1]] for i in matrix]`?

Comment: In Python lingo, you are actually having a list of lists, or a once-nested list. It's helpful to be precise about this, because there are popular libraries which expose matrix datastructures.

Comment: Thank you, that is good to know. I just always see people call nested lists matrices elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension with list slicing:

```
matrix = [[3,5,7,9],
          [6,8,12,14],
          [2,1,0,5],
          [7,8,9,10]]
new_matrix = [i[:2] for i in matrix]
```

Output:

```
[[3, 5], [6, 8], [2, 1], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can iterate over matrix and slice the each list.

```
matrix = [[3, 5, 7, 9],
          [6, 8, 12, 14],
          [2, 1, 0, 5],
          [7, 8, 9, 10]]
new_matrix=[]
for mat in matrix:
    new_matrix.append(mat[:2])
```

Output :

```
[[3, 5], [6, 8], [2, 1], [7, 8]]
```